# PHP assign one array value to another array

Tags: php, arrays

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'label' => '1',
    'index' => 1,
    'product_attributes' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'type' => 'product',
        'id' => 1,
        'label' => 'Size',
        'placeholder' => 'Select Size',
        'description' => '',
        'defaultValue' => 
        array (
          'text' => 'Size32',
          'price' => '22',
          'isSelected' => false,
        ),
        'choices' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Size30',
            'price' => '20',
            'isSelected' => 'true',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Size32',
            'price' => '22',
            'isSelected' => false,
          ),
        ),
        'conditionalLogic' => '',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'type' => 'product',
        'id' => 2,
        'label' => 'Color',
        'placeholder' => 'Select Color',
        'description' => 'DEsc',
        'defaultValue' => 
        array (
          'text' => 'Black',
          'price' => '5',
          'isSelected' => 'false',
        ),
        'choices' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Black',
            'price' => '5',
            'isSelected' => 'false',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Green',
            'price' => '6',
            'isSelected' => 'false',
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Blue',
            'price' => '4',
            'isSelected' => 'true',
          ),
          3 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'White',
            'price' => '1',
            'isSelected' => 'false',
          ),
        ),
        'conditionalLogic' => '',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'type' => 'product',
        'id' => 3,
        'label' => 'Fit',
        'placeholder' => 'Select Fit',
        'description' => 'Select Fit',
        'defaultValue' => 
        array (
        ),
        'choices' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Slim',
            'price' => '2',
            'isSelected' => false,
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Regular',
            'price' => '3',
            'isSelected' => false,
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Casual',
            'price' => '5',
            'isSelected' => false,
          ),
        ),
        'conditionalLogic' => '',
      ),
    ),
    'total_product_cost' => '$27.00',
    'total_product_price' => '27.00',
    'product_id' => '36',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'label21',
    'total_product_cost' => '$27.00',
    'total_product_price' => '27.00',
    'index' => 3,
    'product_id' => '36',
    'product_attributes' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'type' => 'product',
        'id' => 1,
        'label' => 'Size',
        'placeholder' => 'Select Size',
        'description' => '',
        'defaultValue' => 
        array (
          'text' => 'Size32',
          'price' => '22',
          'isSelected' => false,
        ),
        'choices' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Size30',
            'price' => '20',
            'isSelected' => 'true',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Size32',
            'price' => '22',
            'isSelected' => false,
          ),
        ),
        'conditionalLogic' => '',
        'conditionalLogic2' => 
        array (
          'actionType' => 'show',
          'logicType' => 'all',
          'checkbox' => true,
          'rules' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'fieldId' => 2,
              'operator' => 'is',
              'value' => 'Black',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'type' => 'product',
        'id' => 2,
        'label' => 'Color',
        'placeholder' => 'Select Color',
        'description' => 'DEsc',
        'defaultValue' => 
        array (
          'text' => 'Black',
          'price' => '5',
          'isSelected' => 'false',
        ),
        'choices' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Black',
            'price' => '5',
            'isSelected' => 'false',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Green',
            'price' => '6',
            'isSelected' => 'false',
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Blue',
            'price' => '4',
            'isSelected' => 'true',
          ),
          3 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'White',
            'price' => '1',
            'isSelected' => 'false',
          ),
        ),
        'conditionalLogic' => '',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'type' => 'product',
        'id' => 3,
        'label' => 'Fit',
        'placeholder' => 'Select Fit',
        'description' => 'Select Fit',
        'defaultValue' => 
        array (
        ),
        'choices' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Slim',
            'price' => '2',
            'isSelected' => false,
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Regular',
            'price' => '3',
            'isSelected' => false,
          ),
          2 => 
          array (
            'text' => 'Casual',
            'price' => '5',
            'isSelected' => false,
          ),
        ),
        'conditionalLogic' => '',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I have posted my array value. This values are dynamic. Here is two array `conditionalLogic` and `conditionalLogic2` I want to assign those array key `conditionalLogic2` exist and value should be assign to `conditionalLogic`. After assign `conditionalLogic` values into the `conditionalLogic2` remove that key from my array list.

Check I have tried this way but not working -

```
// $data['values'] array I have posted above
foreach ($data['values'] as $products) {
    foreach ($products['product_attributes'] as $product_choices) {
        if (!empty($product_choices['conditionalLogic2']) && $product_choices['conditionalLogic'] == '') {
            $product_choices['conditionalLogic'] = $product_choices['conditionalLogic2'];
            unset($product_choices['conditionalLogic2']);
        }
    }
}
var_export($data['values']); exit;
```

Please help me and give me any solution how to replace the array value into another array.

What is the shortcut way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is `$data['values']` I see nothing called that in your data structure

Comment: Firstly, when you loop over some array, you are working with a copy of the element, not the element itself. To work with the element you need to reference it `foreach ($data['values'] as &$products) {`.

Comment: `$data['values']` data are coming above array format

Comment: Then try `foreach ($products['product_attributes'] as &$product_choices) {`

Comment: And try to use `var_export()` instead of `var_dump()`. In that way your arrays representations can be copy/paste.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ohh yes I forgot to pass array in the second foreach `$products['product_attributes']`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Same output coming :(

Comment: Did you read and undertand @sevavietl comment about passing a reference instead of a copy

Comment: @RiggsFolly check my updated question.

Comment: @sevavietl I have used `var_export()` instead of `print_r()`. Please check my upated question.

Comment: YUK I have to say `print_r()` is easier to read but `var_export()` does allow us to write a text easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually better to avoid nested loops:

```
foreach ($data as &$datum) {
    if (!isset($datum['product_attributes'])) {
        continue;
    }

    $datum['product_attributes'] = array_map(function ($productAttribute) {
        if (
            !empty($productAttribute['conditionalLogic2']) 
            && empty($productAttribute['conditionalLogic'])
        ) {
            $productAttribute['conditionalLogic'] = $productAttribute['conditionalLogic2'];
            unset($productAttribute['conditionalLogic2']);
        }

        return $productAttribute;
    }, $datum['product_attributes']);
}
```

Here I used [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function to assign new arrays directly.

[Here is working example.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7376335d7748a571d6f0b09211fff8cac52dd0ec)

Comment: :) :) :) :) The OP is having trouble understanding  how to process a fairly simple array. And you thing its a good idea to throw ___annonymous functions as parameters to an other funtion at them___.  Well I think this is just to demonstrate how clever you are rather than be of any great assistance to the OP

Comment: I saw your answer. your example working fine. But my local mechine not working fine. I am getting this error message -  `Notice (8): Undefined index: product_attributes [APP\Controller\OrdersController.php, line 378]

Warning (2): array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array [APP\Controller\OrdersController.php, line 378]

Notice (8): Undefined index: product_attributes [APP\Controller\OrdersController.php, line 378]

Warning (2): array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array [APP\Controller\OrdersController.php, line 378]`

Comment: @Chinu Seems that some of your arrays don't have `'product_attributes'`, I will update code in a sec.

Comment: @Chinu Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost right, but you're acting a local variables in foreach loops. You should bind them to original array items as follows:

```
foreach ($data['values'] as & $products) {
    foreach ($products['product_attributes'] as & $product_choices) {
        if (!empty($product_choices['conditionalLogic2']) && $product_choices['conditionalLogic'] == '') {
            $product_choices['conditionalLogic'] = $product_choices['conditionalLogic2'];
            unset($product_choices['conditionalLogic2']);
        }
    }
}
unset($products);
unset($product_choices);
```

If there is the end of current function scope, both `unset` may be omitted. But you may remove references from an array explicitly to avoid undesired affects in some code below in the same scope. I.e. `$products = 10;` somewhere below crushes your last branch of an array.

Comment: Not sure why you have the 2 `unset()` at the end though

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've commented this aspect in my answer

Comment: Yea but its no biggy to just add the 4 lines of code so it is blatantly obvious to the OP what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

@chinu You are actually assigning or changing the local variables where scope is limited within for loop only so in this case, we should use pass by reference.

See the following code, it will work:

```
foreach ($data['values'] as &$products) {
    foreach ($products['product_attributes'] as &$product_choices) {        
        if (!empty($product_choices['conditionalLogic2']) && $product_choices['conditionalLogic'] == '') {
            $product_choices['conditionalLogic'] = $product_choices['conditionalLogic
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: What happened to the rest of his code. Most beginners like us to make it as simple as possible to understand an answer. If you leave to much to the immagination they dont understand

Comment: There is no other code in the post, do let me know if I missed anything. I fixed the code which has the issue.